# Example of using RedLaserSDK in MonoTouch project

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, barcode

Is there any example of using the [RedLaserSDK](http://redlaser.com/sdk/index.php) in a MonoTouch project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are MonoTouch [bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/RedLaser) available for the RedLaser SDK.

The same bindings, a **[sample](http://code.google.com/p/btouch-library/downloads/list)** and some [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/btouch-library/wiki/RedLaserSDK) are also available on google-code.

But the instructions (at least) seems to be out of date. e.g. use **-cxx** option to select the C++ compiler (not the symlinks workaround provided in the wiki).

**UPDATE** Latest RedLaser bindings (newer than mono's git repository) bindings are available at: https://github.com/chrisbranson/monotouch-bindings with **sample** code available at: https://github.com/chrisbranson/RedLaserSample